# Change The Speed of The Timer

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, timer

I have a code that works correctly.This code draws circles with random coordinates on the screen. The code looks like this:

.ts

```
import { Component, NgZone, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {SimpleTimer} from 'ng2-simple-timer';

@Component({
selector: 'canvas_game_component',
templateUrl: 'WebSite/Components/CanvasGameComponent/CanvasGame.html',
styleUrls: ['WebSite/Components/CanvasGameComponent/CanvasGame.css']
})

export class CanvasGameComponent {
public ComponentShapes: Shapes.Shape[] = [];
public Score: number = 0;
public TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes;
public TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape;
public TimeOfDecreaseXCoordinateOfShapes;

constructor() {

}
public Start() {
    this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape = setInterval(() => {
        this.AddShapesToComponentShape();
    }, 350);
    this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes = setInterval(() => {
        this.RefreshCanvasShapes();
    }, 50);
}

public AddShapesToComponentShape() {
    var yCordinateOfCircle: number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 140) + 5);
    var xCordinateOfCircle: number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 5);
    var circle: Shapes.Circle = new Shapes.Circle(xCordinateOfCircle, yCordinateOfCircle, 10);
    this.ComponentShapes.push(circle);
}

public RefreshCanvasShapes() {
    var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById("shape_canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    var i: number;
    this.Score++;
    for (i = 1; i < this.ComponentShapes.length; i++) {
        var probability: number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        this.ComponentShapes[i].Draw(context);
    }
}
}

module Shapes {
export class Shape {
    public XCoordinate: number = 0;
    public YCoordinate: number = 0;

    constructor(xCoordinate: number, yCoordinate: number) {
        this.XCoordinate = xCoordinate;
        this.YCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    }

    public Draw(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {

    }
}

export class Circle extends Shape {
    private Size: number = 0;

    constructor(xCoordinate: number, yCoordinate: number, size: number) {
        super(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        this.Size = size;
    }

    public Draw(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.strokeStyle = "white";
        context.arc(this.XCoordinate, this.YCoordinate, this.Size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = this.Size / 14;
        context.stroke();
    }
}
}
```

.html

```
<div id="canvas_component" class="canvas_component_class">
<div class="menu_side_class">
    <button (click)="Start()">
        click
    </button>
    <a>{{Score}}</a>
</div>
<canvas id="shape_canvas" class="shape_canvas_class"></canvas>
</div>
```

.css

```
.canvas_game_component {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.menu_side_class {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: green;
}

.shape_canvas_class {

background-color: black;
width: 100%;
height: calc(100% - 50px)
}
```

I want to change the speed of the timers when the score is 200 and 400 and 600.I have updated the code for this.

```
import { Component, NgZone, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {SimpleTimer} from 'ng2-simple-timer';

@Component({
selector: 'canvas_game_component',
templateUrl: 'WebSite/Components/CanvasGameComponent/CanvasGame.html',
styleUrls: ['WebSite/Components/CanvasGameComponent/CanvasGame.css']
})

export class CanvasGameComponent {
public ComponentShapes: Shapes.Shape[] = [];
public Score: number = 0;
public TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes;
public TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape;
public TimeOfDecreaseXCoordinateOfShapes;

constructor() {

}
public Start() {
    this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape = setInterval(() => {
        this.AddShapesToComponentShape();
    }, 350);
    this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes = setInterval(() => {
        this.RefreshCanvasShapes();
    }, 50);
}

public AddShapesToComponentShape() {
    var yCordinateOfCircle: number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 140) + 5);
    var xCordinateOfCircle: number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 5);
    var circle: Shapes.Circle = new Shapes.Circle(xCordinateOfCircle, yCordinateOfCircle, 10);
    this.ComponentShapes.push(circle);
}

public IncreaseSpeed() {
    if (this.Score > 200 && this.Score < 300) {
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape);
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes);
        this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape = setInterval(() => {
            this.AddShapesToComponentShape();
        }, 300);
        this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes = setInterval(() => {
            this.RefreshCanvasShapes();
        }, 40);
    }
    else if (this.Score > 300 && this.Score < 400) {
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape);
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes);
        this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape = setInterval(() => {
            this.AddShapesToComponentShape();
        }, 200);
        this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes = setInterval(() => {
            this.RefreshCanvasShapes();
        }, 30);
    }
    else if (this.Score > 400 && this.Score < 500) {
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape);
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes);
        this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape = setInterval(() => {
            this.AddShapesToComponentShape();
        }, 100);
        this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes = setInterval(() => {
            this.RefreshCanvasShapes();
        }, 20);
    }
}

public RefreshCanvasShapes() {
    var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById("shape_canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    var i: number;
    this.Score++;    
    this.IncreaseSpeed();  
    for (i = 1; i < this.ComponentShapes.length; i++) {
            var probability: number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            this.ComponentShapes[i].Draw(context);
    }
}
}

module Shapes {
export class Shape {
    public XCoordinate: number = 0;
    public YCoordinate: number = 0;

    constructor(xCoordinate: number, yCoordinate: number) {
        this.XCoordinate = xCoordinate;
        this.YCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    }

    public Draw(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {

    }
}

export class Circle extends Shape {
    private Size: number = 0;

    constructor(xCoordinate: number, yCoordinate: number, size: number) {
        super(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        this.Size = size;
    }

    public Draw(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "white";
            context.strokeStyle = "white";
        context.arc(this.XCoordinate, this.YCoordinate, this.Size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = this.Size / 14;
        context.stroke();
    }
}
}
```

But when the score is 200, the program stops drawing circle. But when the score exceeds 500, it starts to draw circles again.I'm stopping the timer that calls the AddShapesToComponentShape() function. I change the time of the timer and start it again. But it doesn't add circle.Where am I doing wrong? Or how else can I do what I want? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to don't see anything is because you turn off the timer before you add an new shape. When the score is over 500 you no longer clear the timers and the add shape function gets called

From your code

```
public IncreaseSpeed() {
    if (this.Score > 200 && this.Score < 300) {
        // clears both timers not giving add shape timer a chance to be called.
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape);
        clearInterval(this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes);

        // This will be called every 300 ms 
        this.TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape = setInterval(() => {
            this.AddShapesToComponentShape();
        }, 300);  // << 300ms will happen after the 40ms 

        // this will be called in 40 ms
        // when it does the function RefreshCanvasShapes calls
        // IncreaseSpeed (this function) which clears the 
        // timer TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape
        this.TimeOfRefreshCanvasShapes = setInterval(() => {
            this.RefreshCanvasShapes();
        }, 40);
    }
```

I can not fix your code as what you are doing will always have a variety of problems. You need to use a single animation loop using requestAnimationFrame which fires at 1/60th second.

From that loop you render and take care of any spawning. The example spawns every 300ms. Any timing error does not accumulate, it will maintain the average spawn rate as long as you do not set the rate faster than 17ms

```
var spawnTime; 
var currentSpawnRate = 300;
function mainLoop(time){
     // start the spawning
     if(spawnTime === undefined){
         spawnTime = time + currentSpawnRate;
     }
     if(time > spawnTime){
         // code to spawn what you want
         // change the spawn rate depending on score

         // set the new spawn time
         spawnTime += spawnTime;
     }
     // render the scene

     // call next frame
     requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
// start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

Comment: I understand you. Yes I turn off the timer before I add an new shape. But after that turn on TimeOfAddShapesToComponentShape again. It has to continiue to add again. I do not understand it.

Comment: @osmnfrkn61 When you turn off the timer its gone, setting a new interval restarts from the current time, it does not continue. You are always stopping it before it fires.